# Persisting configuration keys and values with overrides

Tags: database, configuration, persistence, graph-databases, key-value-store

I'm creating a system where there are config keys and values. So for example:

```
config.key = 10
```

Is an example of a configuration key and a value. These keys can also have overrides based on "dimensions". So for example, if we wanted to apply `config.key` to applications with the dimension `foo`, the overridden key would essentially be:

```
config.key.foo = 20
```

In future we may have multiple dimensions in arbitrary order, so this could be a possibility in future:

```
config.key.foo.bar = 30
```

A more concrete example would be if we had a key/toggle called `display.pintrest.feed` that has a `boolean` value. So the default value would be `false`, but you could have overrides like so:

```
display.pintrest.feed = false
display.pintrest.feed.femaleUser = true
```

Here `femaleUser` is a dimension (so we want to set the value of this config to `true` for only female users).

This is essentially what I am trying to do. My question is regarding persistence. What would be the best way to persist this kind of data? This is data that will be queried somewhat frequently but written to less often. The naive solution would be to use MySQL or PostgreSQL and create a table like this:

```
+----------------------------------+-------+
|                Key               | Value |
+----------------------------------+-------+
| config.key                       | 10    |
| config.key.foo                   | 20    |
| display.pintrest.feed            | true  |
| display.pintrest.feed.femaleUser | false |
+----------------------------------+-------+
```

But we lose the type safety of `Value` and also have a single point of failure. We also have a lot of redundancy (the base part of the configuration key is repeated each time). So I wondered about perhaps representing it as a graph so that I could write it to a graph database. I was thinking of modeling it like so:

[image]

Is this viable or overkill?

I don't mind using a simple key-value store either but it should be fault-tolerant and should be able to be clustered. Also we only really care about eventual consistency (i.e., don't mind it taking time to propagate changes to all the nodes).

So my question is whether I should go for a simple key-value store to persist this data, or should I go for a graph database? My rationale for the latter is simply to mitigate the redundancy from keys but I don't know if that's strong rationale.

Comment: at least wiredtiger and sophia have prefix compression which means that keys with similar prefix get their own "bucket". Having the same prefix saves space. But I don't know if there is such a database that is clustered. Have look at cassandra.

Comment: There is now foundationdb.